# bash script if and while conditions

Tags: bash

I am having trouble with executing the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
response=" "
while ["$response" != "q"]; do
echo -n "Please enter a response"; read response
done
```

ALSO

```
!/bin/bash
response="x"

if ["$response" = "x"]
then
echo "the value is x"
fi
```

What could the possible errors be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while and if statements are spaced wrong.

```
while [ "$response" != "q" ]; do etc
```

You need a space between the bracket and the  double quote.

Comment: Thank you good sir! this was my last resort, I spent about 2 hours trying to figure what was wrong.